# Deleting duplicate records in database by comparing them in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

- `table1`:

  ```
                  i_r_p |    prod_id |        dest_id | is_disabled 
  ----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------
                      1 |         11 |           2004 | f
                      2 |         12 |           5112 | f
                      3 |         11 |           1403 | f
                      4 |         12 |           5112 | f
                      5 |         11 |           2944 | f
  ```
- `table2`:

  ```
   i_r_p_v | i_r_p_id |    ven_id | preference 
  ---------+----------+-----------+------------
         1 |        1 |       101 |        190
         2 |        1 |       101 |        250
         3 |        2 |       101 |        500
         4 |        4 |       318 |        125
         5 |        4 |       318 |        225
         6 |        3 |       127 |         50
  ```

**To do:**

I want to delete those entries from `table1`, which have the same `prod_id AND dest_id`.
I want to delete those entries from `table2`, which have the same `(i_r_p_id AND ven_id) AND preference > 100 AND if entries have same preferences then delete any entry, else delete records with less than the highest preference found.`

**My working:**

```
select ven_id, prod_id, dest_id, preference from table2 join table1 on i_r_p_id=i_r_p where preference > 100;
select ven_id, prod_id, dest_id, preference, COUNT(prod_id)from table2 join table1 on i_r_p_id=i_r_p where preference > 100 group by ven_id, prod_id, dest_id, preference having (COUNT(prod_id) > 1);
```

I can not directly run the delete commands on database due to some reasons, and I am unable to extract the exact data which I have to delete.

Comment: Are you looking for deletion operation in both tables or what ?

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ: yes in both tables

Comment: _want to delete those entries from table1, which have the same prod_id AND dest_id_ > for this you could use like this `delete from table1where prod_id =dest_id`,right?

Comment: @MHS you "want to delete those entries from table 1 ..." and at the same time  "can not directly run the delete commands on database due to some reasons,"  (privileges?) I am confused. `DELETE` command is the only way to acctually perform deletion of some rows.

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ: i mean to say that unless i am sure about my queries, i can not run delete commands, coz its really critical data for a company business.

Comment: @MHS that's wise, but even if youl sure about your queries, you should have backup of critical data. Probably your company has got backup policy. You could consider at least making a copy of tables before deletion ex. `CRETE TABLE table1_copy AS SELECT * FROM table1;`.

Comment: Are we allowed to create a temporary table for this exercise?